# Prevent Angular NativeScript WebView from zooming with pinch zoom

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, wkwebview, angular2-nativescript

So I have a Nativescript App using Angular (NG 5.1.1 / Angular 7.x)

I have a view with a webview.

```
    @ViewChild("myWebView") webViewRef: ElementRef;

    <WebView class="webview" #myWebView [src]="myURL"></WebView>
```

Inside my webview.component.ts I have this.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const webview: WebView = this.webViewRef.nativeElement;

    webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
        this.setIndicatorFalse();
        if (webview.ios) {
            webview.ios.scrollView.delegate = UIScrollViewDelegateZ.new();
            webview.ios.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
            webview.ios.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1;
        }
    });
    webview.on(WebView.loadStartedEvent, (args: LoadEventData) => {
        if (webview.android) {
            webview.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webview.android.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        } else {
            // @ts-ignore
            webview.ios.multipleTouchEnabled = false;
            webview.ios.scalesPageToFit = false;
            webview.ios.scrollView.bounces = false;
            webview.ios.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true;
            webview.ios.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
            webview.ios.opaque = false;
            webview.ios.scrollView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
            webview.ios.scrollView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see i've tried all sorts of stuff to get this webview to not pinch zoom.

I am overriding my ViewDelegate with

```
webview.ios.scrollView.delegate = UIScrollViewDelegateZ.new();
```

and that file is here

```
export class UIScrollViewDelegateZ extends NSObject implements UIScrollViewDelegate {

public static ObjCProtocols = [UIScrollViewDelegate];

static new(): UIScrollViewDelegateZ {
    console.log("here we are");

    return <UIScrollViewDelegateZ>super.new();
}

viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView): UIView {
    console.log("viewForZoomingInScrollView");

    return null;
}

scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView): void {
    console.log("scrollViewDidZoom");

    return null;
}

scrollViewWillBeginZoomingWithView(scrollView: UIScrollView, view: UIView): void {
    console.log("scrollViewWillBeginZoomingWithView   " + scrollView);

    return null;
    }
}
```

When I load my webview and pinch zoom my console log says this:

```
 CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/webview/scrollDelegate.js:9:20: here we are
 CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/webview/scrollDelegate.js:21:20: scrollViewWillBeginZoomingWithView   <WKScrollView: 0x7fb140afe000; baseClass = UIScrollView; frame = (0 0; 375 603); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000ab2100>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000537480>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 1916}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
 CONSOLE LOG file:///app/app/webview/scrollDelegate.js:17:20: scrollViewDidZoom
```

So I feel like I am close?? but I just can't get it to go?  I thought I was suppose to return null / undefined when trying to pinch zoom? which is what a few other SO answers / the web say to do but nothing is working.

the HTML page also has the correct metatag headers...

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the default meta data being set by tns-core-modules.

```
import { WebView } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/web-view';

declare var WKUserScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime, WKUserContentController, WKWebViewConfiguration, WKWebView, CGRectZero;

(<any>WebView.prototype).createNativeView = function () {
    const jScript = `var meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
    meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
    meta.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);`;
    const wkUScript = WKUserScript.alloc().initWithSourceInjectionTimeForMainFrameOnly(jScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
    const wkUController = WKUserContentController.new();
    wkUController.addUserScript(wkUScript);
    const configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration.new();
    configuration.userContentController = wkUController;
    configuration.preferences.setValueForKey(
        true,
        "allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"
    );
    return new WKWebView({
        frame: CGRectZero,
        configuration: configuration
    });
};
```

Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=OdkchY), since you are using Angular you may add the above lines to  your `app.component.ts`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try it. This is code specific to ios right? Also I'd like to insert different scripts based on different context - so just redefine `createNativeView` or have an `if` statement inside it?

Comment: I wanted to note that in 2023 this answer no longer works, the webview content fails to load altogether.

Comment: @Justin Yes, you are right this might not work depending on your NativeScript version, the core modules are constantly updated all the time. Could you please confirm the version of NativeScript you are using?