# Is it possible to inject javascript in webview

Tags: webview, nativescript

Is it possible to inject javascript into a third party web-page - i'm trying to pre-fill some INPUT fields.

I've got a feeling the answer will be no - but maybe possible in native code.

Looking at the ios code for WebView - I see that the constructor actually injects it's own JS code. Just wondering how I could also do the same.

I tried to inject during the `loadFinishedEvent` - but I think it's too late.

Maybe I need to sub-class Webview - how would I do that and also be able to specify the new class in xml page definition.

Comment: You can inject javascript by loading an url. So you can try to load that URL after loadFinished and see if it works. See https://medium.com/@filipe.batista/inject-javascript-into-webview-2b702a2a029f

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could inject JavaScript after a web page is loaded. You will have to do it while creating the `WKWebView`.

[Here is another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54454237/1060423) that gives you an example to override the creation of `WKWebView` to inject your own JavaScript. The purpose was to disable pinch zoom.